# Using Web3 to pull block #, hash, and timestamp

Tags: json-rpc, javascript

Can anyone give me advice on using web3 to pull the latest block number, hash and timestamp using Web3? I can't get this to work, and the documentation is fairly weak from what I've seen. Once I pull the values I am going to load them into p elements in my web page, so that's why I have the getElementByID statements. script and HTML code below

```
//connect web3 and check if web3 is connected correctly
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
    }
    if(web3.isConnected()) {
    console.log("connected"); 
    } else {
    console.log("not connected")
    }

//pulls state information from the blockchain
    web3.eth.filter('latest').changed(function(){
      var blockNumber = web3.eth.number;
      document.getElementById('latestBlock').innerText = blockNumber;
      var hash = web3.eth.getBlockNumber();
      document.getElementById('latestBlockHash').innerText = hash;
      var timeStamp = web3.eth.block(blockNumber).timestamp;
      document.getElementById('latestBlockTimestamp').innerText = Date(timeStamp);
    });





<div class="container">
      <h2>Blockchain Monitor</h2>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Ethereum Network</div>
        <div class="panel-body"> 
            <h5>Coinbase Address: <strong id="coinbase"></strong></h5>
            <h5>Latest Block Number: <strong id="latestBlock"></strong></h5>
            <h5>Latest Block Timestamp: <strong id="latestBlockTimestamp"></strong></h5>
            <h5>Latest Block Hash: <strong id="latestBlockHash"></strong></h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Block number is retrieved by:

```
var blockNumber = web3.eth.blockNumber;
```

Block hash is retrieved by:

```
var blockHash = web3.eth.getBlock(blockNumber).hash;
```

Timestamp is:

```
var timestamp = web3.eth.getBlock(blockNumber).timestamp;
```

Read the documentation here for more: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API

Comment: much appreciated, I got it to work with an onload function and your above statements

Comment: of course! make sure to confirm the answer (green check) if it worked

Comment: quick follow up, if I want to pull the latest transaction hash, would the statement be:

Comment: var txnHash = web3.eth.getTransaction;

Comment: See: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransaction var txn = web3.eth.getTransaction(txnHash); But this assumes you know the transaction hash. I don't think you can pull an arbitrary "latest transaction" because transactions in the mempool aren't ordered.

Answer (score 4):

Since web3 1.x, most functions changed to promises. In order to reach these values in an async function:

```
const blockNumber = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber();
const blockHash = await web3.eth.getBlock(await web3.eth.getBlockNumber()))
                    .hash;
const timestamp = await web3.eth.getBlock(await web3.eth.getBlockNumber()))
                    .timestamp
```