# In web3, how can I fetch a range of block timestamps most efficiently?

Tags: web3js, timestamp

Given a range of block numbers, how can I most efficiently fetch the timestamps for those blocks?  I couldn't find a simple call to fetch the timestamp at a certain height other than fetching the full blocks.  Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Have you tried js dot notation or using jq?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28192/using-web3-to-pull-block-hash-and-timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient way would probably be to use [Google BigQuery](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery) which has entire Ethereum blockchain data indexed and available as public data set.  The following query:

```sql
SELECT number, timestamp
FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.blocks`
WHERE number >= 1000000 AND number < 1000010
ORDER BY number;
```

gives me the following output:

```
    number  timestamp   
1   1000000 2016-02-13 22:54:13 UTC
2   1000001 2016-02-13 22:54:18 UTC
3   1000002 2016-02-13 22:54:38 UTC
4   1000003 2016-02-13 22:54:40 UTC
5   1000004 2016-02-13 22:55:00 UTC
6   1000005 2016-02-13 22:55:08 UTC
7   1000006 2016-02-13 22:55:10 UTC
8   1000007 2016-02-13 22:55:57 UTC
9   1000008 2016-02-13 22:56:00 UTC
10  1000009 2016-02-13 22:56:14 UTC
```

Comment: Ah perfect, this is exactly the sort of thing Iwas looking for.  Thank you!